# convert file from bytes in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

Open byte values, that byte contains "textfile"

I have an android code for convert file from bytes values

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
File myDir = new File(root);

File fileWithinMyDir = new File(myDir, filename); 
FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);

ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(dest));

ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
entry.setSize(input.length);
zos.putNextEntry(entry);
zos.write(input);
zos.closeEntry();
zos.close();
```

but I tried in swift 4

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                        .appendingPathComponent("/download.zip")

print(fileURL)

if let outputStream = OutputStream(url: fileURL, append: true) 
{

    outputStream.open()

    let bytesWritten = outputStream.write(bytes, maxLength: 1024)

    if bytesWritten < 0
    {

        print("write failure")

    }

    outputStream.close().
}
```

I save to document directory and open the txt file it has following message displayed when open txt file

> The document could not be opened.The file isn't in the correct format

how to open that bytes any one help me

Comment: The Android code does no conversion, it compress a file to a zip archive. Swift would need a library for that since it does have no native library for zip archiving.

Comment: Thank you but main reason is I want convert "bytes value" to file

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.